# Spark job reading the sorted AVRO files in dataframe, but writing to kafka without order

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, avro

I have AVRO files sorted with ID and each ID has folder called "ID=234" and data inside the folder is in AVRO format and sorted on the basis of date.
I am running spark job which takes input path and reads avro in dataframe. This dataframe then writes to kafka topic with 5 partition.

```
val properties: Properties = getProperties(args)


val spark = SparkSession.builder().master(properties.getProperty("master"))
  .appName(properties.getProperty("appName")).getOrCreate()
val sqlContext = spark.sqlContext

val sourcePath = properties.getProperty("sourcePath")

val dataDF = sqlContext.read.avro(sourcePath).as("data")
val count = dataDF.count();
val schemaRegAdd = properties.getProperty("schemaRegistry")

val schemaRegistryConfs = Map(
  SchemaManager.PARAM_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL          -> schemaRegAdd,
  SchemaManager.PARAM_VALUE_SCHEMA_NAMING_STRATEGY -> SchemaManager.SchemaStorageNamingStrategies.TOPIC_NAME
)
val start = Instant.now

dataDF.select(functions.struct(properties.getProperty("message.key.name")).alias("key"), functions.struct("*").alias("value"))
  .toConfluentAvroWithPlainKey(properties.getProperty("topic"), properties.getProperty("schemaName"),
  properties.getProperty("schemaNamespace"))(schemaRegistryConfs)
  .write.format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers",properties.getProperty("kafka.brokers"))
  .option("topic",properties.getProperty("topic")).save()
```

}

My use case is to write all messages from each ID (sorted on date) sequencially such as all sorted data from one ID 1 should be added first then from ID 2 and so on. Kafka message has key as ID.

Answer (score 0):

Dont forgot that the data inside a RDD/dataset is shuffle when you do transformations so you lose the order.

the best way to achieve this is to read file one by one and send it to kafka instead of read a full directory in your `val sourcePath = properties.getProperty("sourcePath")`

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Even though I iterate over partitioned directories, spark job splits the file in multiple partition and processes the data in parallel. So ends up with mixed data.